# Failed to parse role mappings file - Elastic Search shield

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

Getting this exception:

**Failed to parse role mappings file [C:\abc\ShieldConfig\shield\role_mapping.yml]. skipping/removing all mappings...
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied**("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\abc\ShieldConfig\shield\role_mapping.yml" "read")

ElasticSearch.yml file:

```
    shield:
      authc:
        realms:
          ldap1:
            type: ldap
            order: 0
            url: "LDAP://dir.svc.abc.com"
            user_dn_templates:
              - "cn={0},ou=people,dc=dir,dc=svc,dc=abc,dc=com"
            group_search:
              base_dn: "ou=people,dc=dir,dc=svc,dc=abc,dc=com"
            files:
              role_mapping: 'C:\abc\ShieldConfig\shield\role_mapping.yml'
```

How to fix this issue? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems Shield can't read the file in `C:\abc\ShieldConfig\shield\role_mapping.yml` (i.e. there is a `read` `FilePermission` access denied in the error). Can you verify/fix that file access permission?

Comment: try running program with administrator privileges.try "Run as administrator"

Comment: Hi Van and Java-ledge... Tried both of the solutions but still it is not working out.

Comment: Any update on this please?